# How to format the xml in java dom parser?

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Request>

<Id>
```

here the first tag  was written into file followed by xml version, i need that need to write in next line. like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Request>
  <Id>
```

i Have use below code to write the xml into file,please help

```
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory
                .newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(
                Constants.xmlLocation
                        + Constants.metaDataXmlFileName
                        + format.format(calendar.getTime()) + ".xml"));

        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(
                "{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "5");
        transformer.transform(source, result);
```

Comment: its already answered, check this post here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139076/how-to-pretty-print-xml-from-java

Comment: Also this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142632/java-dom-xml-file-create-have-no-tabs-or-whitespaces-in-output-file?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

You can try the code below, this will work fine and you will be getting the formatted output

```
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.DOCTYPE_PUBLIC,"yes");
transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "10");
```